# Black Screen after fresh install of ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, system-installation

After fresh install for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and after typing some commands as:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Than I changed the additional driver to nvidia priority and tested it, I restarted computer, but a black screen appears which says *cleaning*, then after cleaning another black screen appear with "-" at the top left corner.

I've installed it till now for 4 times or more I guess, so please any help ..

Comment: Have you tried the `nomodeset` boot option workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem behind this is the proprietary Nvidia drivers , try again a new installation only this time go to Nvidia page and download from them the latest drivers and install them.

If this doesn't work ether i am afraid that you have to use the free-open-source drives (which is not a bad thing to do btw) since we can't make any changes to the Nvidia proprietary drivers, **only the company who is behind this can make changes** BUT the alternative choices you got is:

**1.** You can try other distros such as [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) maybe the proprietary drivers will work better there, AGAIN it depends from the Nvidia company if they gonna work ok **NOT** from the free-open-source community.

**2.** Stay with the free-open-source drivers until Nvidia make an updated version of their drivers by checking their page very often.

**3.** Wait with the free-open-source drives until someone else answers to this question because i don't use the unity UI.